# Cannot detect serial ports available under Windows 10 with winAPI tools

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port

My program normally detects what Serial Ports are available from the OS at start up. It is a simple method of polling if a port can be accessed by name.

project defines for serial port

```
std::string COMPortNumber[MAXPORTS] {"\\\\.\\COM1",  "\\\\.\\COM2",  "\\\\.\\COM3",  "\\\\.\\COM4",  "\\\\.\\COM5",
                                 "\\\\.\\COM6",  "\\\\.\\COM7",  "\\\\.\\COM8",  "\\\\.\\COM9",  "\\\\.\\COM10",
                                 "\\\\.\\COM11", "\\\\.\\COM12", "\\\\.\\COM13", "\\\\.\\COM14", "\\\\.\\COM15",
                                 "\\\\.\\COM16", "\\\\.\\COM17", "\\\\.\\COM18", "\\\\.\\COM19", "\\\\.\\COM20"};

std::string COMPortName[MAXPORTS] = {"com1",  "com2",  "com3",  "com4",  "com5",  "com6",  "com7",  "com8",  "com9", "com10",
                                "com11", "com12", "com13", "com14", "com15", "com16", "com17", "com18", "com19", "com20"};
```

polling function:

```
void updateSerialList(){
ComboBox_ResetContent(SerialPortDropDown); //clears all content from drop down box
//int iresult = ComboBox_AddString(SerialPortDropDown, "Update Port List\0");
for(int n=0; n<MAXPORTS; n++)
{
    COMPortAvailable[n] = serial.getComPortList( COMPortNumber[n] );
    if(COMPortAvailable[n] == true)
    {
        char* tempBuf = new char[COMPortName[n].length() + 1];
        for(unsigned int t=0; t<COMPortName[n].length(); t++)
        {
            tempBuf[t] = COMPortName[n][t];
        }
        tempBuf[COMPortName[n].length()] = '\0';
        int iResult = ComboBox_AddString(SerialPortDropDown, tempBuf);
        {
            if(iResult == CB_ERR){std::cout << "error adding string" << std::endl;}
            else if(iResult == CB_ERRSPACE){std::cout << "error no room" << std::endl;}
        }
        delete[] tempBuf;
    }
}
//place baud rates in select box
for(int n=NUMBERBAUDRATES-1; n>-1; n--)
{
    char* tempBuf = new char[BaudRateName[n].length() + 1];
    for(unsigned int t=0; t<BaudRateName[n].length(); t++)
    {
        tempBuf[t] = BaudRateName[n][t];
    }
    tempBuf[BaudRateName[n].length()] = '\0';
    int iResult = ComboBox_AddString(BaudRateDropDown, tempBuf);
    {
        if(iResult == CB_ERR){std::cout << "error adding string" << std::endl;}
        else if(iResult == CB_ERRSPACE){std::cout << "error no room" << std::endl;}
    }
    delete[] tempBuf;
}
```

This compiles a list in a dropdown box for the user to select. It uses a function in a class for a serial instance. This is the function call inside the class.

```
bool getComPortList(std::string portName)
{
    bool test;
    HANDLE testSerial;
    testSerial = CreateFile(   (portName.c_str())  , GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, NULL, NULL);
    if(testSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        test = false;
    }
    else
    {
        test = true;
        cout << "port number " << portName << " is available" << endl;
    }
    CloseHandle(testSerial);
    return test;
}
```

This method has worked fine until I tried running the program on Windows 10. It previously was tested and used on Vista, Win7, Win 8.1 however even if the Windows10 device manager says comm ports are available on the system, my program cannot get a list of them.

What is different about Win10 serial port access?

Comment: at first this method is very ugly and not correct. you need `CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT,..)` at second if "not work" - look where is error returned

Comment: This is changing, IoT is being hyped, well supported by the Windows.Devices namespace and nobody likes having to support these legacy virtual COM ports anymore.  You'll need to find another driver for whatever device you are using.

Comment: and if `CreateFile` return `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` this not mean that file not exist. you need call `GetLastError()` and only if it return `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` - file really not exist. i guess you got `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` instead

Comment: This program is used simply to send and receive serial ASCII messages from an embedded device. It also allows sending configuration messages to the device also strictly ASCII lines. My end users of the device do not all have win10 laptops. So question is if I do implement a windows.devices namespace will it be backward compatible? Not everyone buys a new laptop. I still have one running Vista.        About calling the get last error, if I were to get access denied then the port is still not available for my use so what to do then?

Comment: what you try todo - determinate lists of all com ports or use some port ? for first task you need use `CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT,..)`. the com device usually exclusive. this mean - only one client can open it. you can easy test this if call `CreateFile` twice - if first call return you ok (handle), second return to you `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. *what to do then?* - nothing - or show message for user with this error

Comment: I'm trying to simply create a list of available com ports so the user can select the one they are needing. Typically the one Windows assigned to a USB-serial adapter. Since they often don't know to look for it under the device manager of Windows, I want to list them for them. The user then selects the com port and a baud rate to connect with. I am about to look up the cm get device function.

Answer (score 2):

your main logic error, that you assume - if `CreateFile` for some *name* return `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` - this mean that this *name* not exist. but this is of course false, because `CreateFile` can fail by different reasons. you need call `GetLastError` after fail. only if it return `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` the *name* really not exist (`ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` can not be for `"\\\\.\\COMX"` because path here always exist and correct). for com devices very common error was `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` - because it have `DO_EXCLUSIVE` flag. with this flag [only one file on device can be open at a time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/specifying-exclusive-access-to-device-objects).

however for enumerate com devices - you need enumerate interfaces for `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT` via `CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW`

```
enumInterfaces(const_cast<PGUID>(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT));

static volatile UCHAR guz;

void enumInterfaces(PGUID InterfaceClassGuid)
{
    CONFIGRET status;
    ULONG len = 0, cb = 0, rcb;
    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
    PWSTR buf = 0;

    do 
    {
        if (status = CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_SizeW(&len, InterfaceClassGuid, 0, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT))
        {
            break;
        }

        if (cb < (rcb = len * sizeof(WCHAR)))
        {
            len = (cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = (PWSTR)alloca(rcb - cb), stack)) / sizeof(WCHAR);
        }

        status = CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW(InterfaceClassGuid, 0, buf, len, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT);

        if (status == CR_SUCCESS)
        {
            while (*buf)
            {
                DbgPrint("use this name in CreateFile = %S\n", buf);

                PrintFriendlyNameByInterface(buf);

                buf += 1 + wcslen(buf);
            }
        }

    } while (status == CR_BUFFER_SMALL);
}

CONFIGRET PrintFriendlyNameByInterface(PCWSTR pszDeviceInterface)
{
    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 64;

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
    DEVPROPTYPE PropertyType;

    CONFIGRET status;

    union {
        PVOID pv;
        PWSTR DeviceID;
        PBYTE pb;
    };

    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            rcb = cb = RtlPointerToOffset(pv = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        status = CM_Get_Device_Interface_PropertyW(pszDeviceInterface, &DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId, &PropertyType, pb, &rcb, 0);

        if (status == CR_SUCCESS)
        {
            if (PropertyType == DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING)
            {
                DbgPrint("DeviceID = %S\n", DeviceID);

                status = PrintFriendlyNameByDeviceID(DeviceID);
            }
            else
            {
                status = CR_WRONG_TYPE;
            }

            break;
        }

    } while (status == CR_BUFFER_SMALL);

    return status;
}

CONFIGRET PrintFriendlyNameByDeviceID(PWSTR DeviceID)
{
    DEVINST dnDevInst;

    CONFIGRET status = CM_Locate_DevNodeW(&dnDevInst, DeviceID, CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL);

    if (status == CR_SUCCESS)
    {
        ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 256;

        PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

        DEVPROPTYPE PropertyType;

        union {
            PVOID pv;
            PWSTR sz;
            PBYTE pb;
        };

        do 
        {
            if (cb < rcb)
            {
                rcb = cb = RtlPointerToOffset(pv = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
            }

            status = CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW(dnDevInst, &DEVPKEY_NAME, &PropertyType, pb, &rcb, 0);

            if (status == CR_SUCCESS)
            {
                if (PropertyType == DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING)
                {
                    DbgPrint("show this name for user = %S\n", sz);
                }
                else
                {
                    status = CR_WRONG_TYPE;
                }
            }

        } while (status == CR_BUFFER_SMALL);
    }

    return status;
}
```

and demo output:

```
use this name in CreateFile = \\?\ACPI#PNP0501#0#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}
DeviceID = ACPI\PNP0501\0
show this name for user = Communications Port (COM1)
```

---

in my system `\\?\ACPI#PNP0501#0#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}` is symbolic link to *PDO* device `\Device\00000034` (created by *aspi.sys*) and it have not `DO_EXCLUSIVE` flag. despite this on second call of CreateFile i got access denied error. to this device *FDO* - `\Device\Serial0` (`\\?\COM1` symbolic link to it) attached. it already have `DO_EXCLUSIVE` flag. anyway `SerialCreateOpen` (`IRP_MJ_CREATE` procedure *serial.sys*) denied access create more than one file - at very begin in increment some counter in device extension, and if it != 1 - return `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`

so even if we try open *PDO* (`\\?\ACPI#PNP0501#0#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}`) which not exclusive device ([*setting the exclusive flag for the FDO has no effect*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/specifying-exclusive-access-to-device-objects) here) - the create request begin execute on stack top from `\Device\Serial0` and *serial.sys* [enforce exclusivity themselves within their](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/specifying-exclusive-access-to-device-objects) `SerialCreateOpen` routine.

[image]

Comment: The wording around handles and objects can be subtle. When we talk about opening a handle, we mean creating a new handle by opening an object by name or reference. So exclusive access here means the Device is normally limited to one File object reference as enforced by the type's parse procedure, but we can actually have multiple handles for this File via duplication or inheritance.

Comment: Additional File references are generally allowed for an exclusive device when opening relative to another File reference (i.e. using the existing handle as the `RootDirectory`), but apparently the `IRP_MJ_CREATE` function of the Serial device (`SerialCreateOpen`) denies access even in this case. Can you confirm that?

Comment: @eryksun - yes. you correct. we can potential create additional handle if use relative open - https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Io/iomgr/parse.c#L87. but for this we need initially have handle to device. from kernel we also can call `IoCreateFile` with `IO_ATTACH_DEVICE` option. so really can be more than one handle :) this is documented [Specifying Exclusive Access to Device Objects](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/specifying-exclusive-access-to-device-objects) . but for user mode app, if com port already open, we (if have not handle)

Comment: for relative open) - can not open it again.

Comment: also from same link - *If two objects in the device stack are named (which is not recommended), the I/O manager allows a single handle to be opened for each object*

Comment: @eryksun - about `SerialCreateOpen` need look, can not say and look this just now

Comment: Naming two devices in a stack... do we have an example of this in a standard installation? It seems like they're just covering their bases because it's the reference count on the parsed device that gets checked but the IRP starts at the top of the device stack.

Comment: @eryksun - in my case *PDO* ( `\\?\ACPI#PNP0501#0#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}` symbolic link to `\Device\00000034` created by *acpi.sys*  **no** `DO_EXCLUSIVE` flag ) and *FDO* ( `\Device\Serial0`, exist `DO_EXCLUSIVE` flag) both named. but you correct `SerialCreateOpen` increment some counter in device extesion, and if it != 1 - return `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`

Comment: [*only one handle to the device can be open at a time*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/specifying-exclusive-access-to-device-objects) - this of course not exactly. need say only one **file** on the device can be open at a time - handle we can duplicate - in this case 2 different handles will be point to the same file