# Java: Can't open COM port on windows 10

Tags: java, serial-port, windows-10

I have an interface that communicate with computer via USB and virtual port. Interface base on C8051F320 chip from Silicon Labs.
I have two programms, one written in Java (that i try to modify), second in QT. Everything works fine on WIN7 and WIN8, but Java software doesn't work on WIN10.

Everything works fine on WIN7 and WIN8, but Java software doesn't work on WIN10.
I use jSerialComm library in my Java project. 
Also i try to use RXTX library. Program works fine on WIN7 but on Win10 gives me 'port in use exception. Unknown Application'.
My COM port is shown at DeviceManager and driver is installed properly (bauds 9600, data bits 8, stop bits 1 …), but i can't open port in Java programm .

I checkd my COM ports configuration on windows cmd by 'mode' command. It gives me strange result, different than 
i get from DeviceManager:

### Status for device COM11:

```
Baud:            8453999
Parity:          8453999
Data Bits:       188
Stop Bits:       188
Timeout:         OFF
XON/XOFF:        OFF
CTS handshaking: OFF
DSR handshaking: OFF
DSR sensitivity: OFF
DTR circuit:     OFF
RTS circuit:     ON
```

I can't change baud parameter of this port by 'mode' command.

I use VirtualBox with WIN7 to check my interface. 
When i connect to interface from VM and next disconnect, settings of my COM port under WIN10 get change. Now 'mode' command gives me that:

### Status for device COM11:

```
Baud:            9600
Parity:          None
Data Bits:       8
Stop Bits:       1
Timeout:         OFF
XON/XOFF:        OFF
CTS handshaking: OFF
DSR handshaking: OFF
DSR sensitivity: OFF
DTR circuit:     OFF
RTS circuit:     ON
```

Java program worked fine after that. Unfortunelly problem came back after few connect and disconect of interface to USB. 
I don't know it is Java or WIN10 issue. Is the way to set COM port properties via Java before open it?

Comment: Same here, listing ports has result 0. Will try https://github.com/github-byl/Java-RxTx-in-Windows-10-USB-COM-ports

Comment: Found this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46366234/cannot-detect-serial-ports-available-under-windows-10-with-winapi-tools
Could be a systematic error in native RXTX with Windows 10